# Configure Netplan for 2 subnets

Tags: networking, server

Wanting to have linux server span both sides of a router. to provide services to home and
vpn connection to a VPS server remotely.

The main router is AT&T issued and cascading router is broken.
Network connections

Main router 192.168.2.254

adgaurd home at 192.168.2.2 for dns from the home router

linux server 192.168.2.10

home router 192.168.0.1
all pc's and wifi devices.
This sets up all user devices behind a double nat to the internet.
No extra routes are set on the home router.

have 2nd nic interface installed in linux box want to be 192.168.0.10 on the lan side of home router. want to bridge br0 to both 192.168.2.10 and 192.168.0.10 with routing traffic through
it.  Whenever connected on lan side of 192.168.0.1, network suffers, reduction in speed and slows down this network.

This is for all traffic on the network, other machines accessing the internet. This continues until a physically unplug the linux box from the home router.

I thought disabling dhcp, and not assigning the gateway to 192.168.0.1 would prevent this but
Where am I going wrong or are there any suggestions.

current netplan

```
network:    ethernets:

    enp3s6:    # 192.168.2.10
        dhcp4: yes
        dhcp4-overrides:
            route-metric: 100
    enp2s0:     #cannot get to operate
        dhcp4: no
        addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]

  version: 2

  bridges:

    br0:
        interfaces: [enp3s6]
        dhcp4: true
```

Comment: How do you mean "network suffers, reduction in speed and slows down this network"? This box only, or all devices on that network? What default route do you have on your Linux box? How are you changing the routes on your home network to access the "main" network? Have you changed the default route, or added additional routes? Please edit your question with your answers

Answer (score 0):

My problem turned out to be dhcp6

I needed change enp2s0: definition to

enp2s0:

```
 dhcp4: no

 dhcp6: no

 addresses: [192.168.0.10/24]
```